# Problema al cargar URL

Tags: javascript

he intentado colocar una imagen sobre con canvas y hasta aquí todo bien:

```
 var hats = {
      santa: new Image()
    }

    hats.santa.src = "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-TLqidoaU-g4/V1UwLG1dWvI/AAAAAAAAC34/4RpuUek_09UwHRsb7HEnaFs8j8OiEhZAwCLcB/s320/pvPMlO2.png";

    if (this.nameSkin.indexOf('pluses') !== -1) {
      mainCtx.save();
      mainCtx.globalAlpha = 1;
      //mainCtx.drawImage(hats.santa, this.x - Math.max(this.size * .19, this._nameSize * .8), this.y - Math.max(this.size * .30, this._nameSize * .8), 0.47 * this.size, 0.47 * this.size);
      mainCtx.drawImage(hats.santa, this.x - this.size, this.y - this.size, 2 * this.size, 2 * this.size);
      drawText(this.x - Math.max(this.size * .0, this._nameSize * .0), this.y - Math.max(this.size * .05), '101', this._nameSize * 0.5, false);
      mainCtx.restore();
    }
```

Luego he intentado que el src de la imagen santa , fuera por una url enviada por el usuario , haciendo lo siguiente:

```
function recibirUrl() {

var urlcompleta = document.getElementById('url').value;

 var hats = {
      santa: new Image()
    }
hats.santa.src = urlcompleta;



}
```

**EN EL HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="url">
<input type="submit" onClick="recibirUrl()">
```

**Pero ante todo esto , la imagen no me aparece , no sé cual es el error , soy novato en javascript, gracias!**

Answer (score 1):

Estimado Eduardo, colocas un botón para enviar el formulario pero antes de ser enviado ejecutas la **funcion** **`recibirUrl()`**, la cual intenta cargar la imagen pero todo esto ocurre tan rápido que se refresca la pagina (por el envío del formulario) que no da tiempo de ver la nueva imagen, te recomiendo hacer lo siguiente:

Cambia tu **código HTML** como sigue:

```
<input type="text" id="url" onChange="recibirUrl()">
<input type="submit">
```

Comment: me podrias explicar mas?

Comment: probaste el código que te deje?.. cual fue el resultado de dicha prueba?.. si ya lo hiciste y los resultados fueron los esperados dime cual es tu inquietud exactamente y con gusto te ayudare.